# Strange result in the bibliography with @misc

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

I'm writing a paper for an [Elsevier](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/homepage.cws_home) journal using the [template](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/authorsview.authors/elsarticle) the provide.
For the bibliography I'm using the style `model1-num-names`.

I have a reference with the following bibtex:

```
@Misc{SCA,
  title =    {{Service Component Architecture (SCA)}},
  note =     {\url{http://www.osoa.org}},
  key = {SCA}
}
```

It results in the bibliography with same strange `?`.

```
[7] SCA, Service Component Architecture (SCA), ???? http://www. osoa.org.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The style requires a year field:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
The style file: model1-num-names.bst
Database file #1: test.bib
Warning--empty year in SCA; set to ????
(There was 1 warning)
```

If you *really* have no year to put in, one can maybe try a solution. I don't know how the people at Elsevier would accept it.